# How to concate two elements of XML using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Testcases>
    <Testcase_Name>t1</Testcase_Name>
    <Arguments>arg1</Arguments>
</Testcases>
<Testcases>
    <Testcase_Name>t2</Testcase_Name>
    <Arguments>arg2</Arguments>
</Testcases>
```

Above is my code, I want to concate t1 and arg1, t2 and arg2. How can I do that with xmlstarlet?

Answer (score 0):

You firstly need to add `</Root>` to the end of your data above.
ie

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Testcases>
    <Testcase_Name>t1</Testcase_Name>
    <Arguments>arg1</Arguments>
</Testcases>
<Testcases>
    <Testcase_Name>t2</Testcase_Name>
    <Arguments>arg2</Arguments>
</Testcases>
</Root>
```

Then if this is saved as your.test.xml.file

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -B -t -m '//Testcases' -v './Testcase_Name' -o ' , ' -v './Arguments' -n your.test.xml.file
```

Selects nodes named "Testcases" and loops through them printing the values of child nodes named Testcase_Names and Arguments, separated by the -o parameter.

Output is;

```
t1 , arg1
t2 , arg2
```

Omit -o ' , ' to get t1arg1 and t2arg2